# Variables are supposed to be equal, but are not - Python 3

Tags: python, variables

I am writing a simple code to generate two random numbers from 1 to 10 and then the user would have to answer it. However, when I am comparing the correct answer of the question to the number user has inputted, they **appear to be unequal**. I printed the variable and it was exactly the same as what I had input. I am quite new to python and just wanted to make a little code to get familiar.

Code and output is listed below

**Code:**

```
answer = 0
num1 = random.randint(0,9)
num2 = random.randint(0,9)

result = num1 + num2
print(result)
print(num1, "+", num2)

answer = input("Answer: ")
if result == answer:
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Incorrect")

input("Press ENTER to exit")
```

**Output:**

```
5
4 + 1
Answer: 5
Incorrect
Press ENTER to exit
```

Comment: `sum` is a python function, it shouldn't be the name of a variable

Comment: `answer` is a string, `sum` is a number. See the difference with `print(repr(sum), repr(answer))`.

Comment: `input()` returns string. "1" is_not_ equal to 1. use `int(input())`.

Comment: I think that python `input` converts to string, so in the end you may be comparing a string with a int, which will away return false...

Comment: @Yago `input` doesn't "convert" to string, it simply *accepts* only strings. Anything and everything you *type* into your computer is by default and by definition a string, unless explicitly interpreted as and converted to some other more specific type.

Comment: As mentioned above, sum is a built in function. I would practice naming your variables to something more telling and relative to your task. Doing so will not only create more readable code, but will prevent similar instances from occurring.

Comment: @deceze it was not what the official python doc says

`If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: @Yago That is somewhat misleading without context. It converts it *from (external) binary input to a Python `str`.* It does not, say, accept a number as input and then goes out of its way to turn it into a string nonetheless.